# Joomla not showing menu

Tags: joomla, menu, module

I have downloaded this [template](http://www.joomla24.com/remository/finishdown/5193.html) to my joomla 2.5.6 and I'm trying to create a horizontal menu. I have created menu and module that should be displaying that menu. I have set position to user3 (as I've read that is the default position for horizontal menu), but nothing showed up. 
The only positions I can see my menu on are "search" and "top-panel".

Can anybody please guide me how to find what may cause the problem?

EDIT: I have renamed the menu to "menu1" and so did with "menu type" and it has showed up. Why? Where's any logic?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have set on which pages to activate the menu:

[image]

You can find these settings in the module manager > your menu

Comment: I have set "Module assignment: on all pages"

Answer (score 0):

check the positions using ?tp=1 at the end of your url

Comment: I have tried this, unfortunately names of the positions are not shown, there is only "[object Arguments]" text over every position

Answer (score 0):

log in to your joomla backend.

go to article manager and create an article..

go to menu manager and create a new menu, select your article which will me mostly a single article if you have created others then choose others, such as featured article or others,

then on the same page on required setting choose the article you have created.

save and close..

now go to 
module manager,
go to the menu or content menu or horizontal menu,
down below there will be menu assignment,
choose the menu and show to it all pages..

hope this will help you..
Thanks
Anil Bikram Thapa